# A basic formula for the falling factorial

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Whis is a question I asked on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440650/a-basic-formula-for-the-falling-factorial), but didn't get any response.

Suppose we have a family $\mathfrak{A}$ of some subsets of $\Omega$, which is locally finite, i.e.
$$
X(\omega): = \sum_{A \in \mathfrak{A}} \mathbf{1}_{A}(\omega) <\infty
$$
for all $\omega\in \Omega$.

Then for any $k\ge 1$,
$$
(X)_l = X(X-1)\cdots(X-k+1) = \sum_{\text{distinct } A_1,\dots,A_k \in \mathfrak A} \mathbf{1}_{A_{1} \cap \dots \cap A_{k}}.\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
The formula \eqref{1} is very basic, but is very useful for computing factorial moments. Does it have a name? Or maybe there is a reference?

Comment: It is not about probability: if we have $X$ guys (=sets containing $\omega$), there are $X(X-1)...(X-k+1)$ sequences consisting of $k$ distinct guys. In Russian books for children this was called размещения (with сочетания for binomial coefficients: when you divide by $k!$).

Comment: @FedorPetrov: in English, especially for grade-school level math, we also have the same distinction between "permutations" and "combinations."

Comment: @Sam aren't permutations reserved for "complete" permutations (of all elements, thus enumerated by usual factorials)?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: In advanced math, yes. In math for grade-schoolers, no (see, e.g. https://www.mathplanet.com/education/pre-algebra/probability-and-statistic/combinations-and-permutations). Sometimes even you see the notation "n P k" $= n! / (n-k)!$, compared with the notation "n C k" $= n!/ (k! (n-k)!)$.

Comment: Pretty misleading. We had $A_n^k$ notation for this $n!/(n-k)!$. Possibly, coming from "arrangements".

Comment: @SamHopkins, as in the functions on a [Casio calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casio#/media/File:Fx-991EX.jpg) above the $\times$ and $\div$ buttons

Comment: So from the comments I guess that it would be enough to write that this computes permutations (arrangements).